# How do I add spellcheck / dictionaries in macos Sierra? Got .aff and .dic files

Tags: spellcheck, spelling

I'm specifically trying to install system-wide support for Bulgarian. Tried looking for library/spelling but seems to be missing in macos Sierra. Got .aff and .dic files but... now what? Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem (with another language), where do I find the aff and dic files? Are these mac specific or universal?

Answer (score 2):

Put them in Home/Library/Spelling.  To get to Home/Library, you hold down the option key while doing Finder > Go

Comment: Thank you Tom, but in Sierra there seems to be no Spelling folder. By following you instructions i go to home/library/services and can't add files there.

Comment: @RadoslavRaykov That's not right, in Home/Library you should see a couple dozen folders, including (in the "s" area) services, sounds, spelling, suggestions.

Comment: And then? Do I have to restart or reload the OS or particular app? I'm not seeing anything different after copying the `.dic` and `.aff` files to my `~/Library/Spelling/`

Comment: @hippietrail  You should be able to see a entry for the language you added with "(Library)" after the name in system settings > keyboard > text input > edit > spelling

Comment: @TomGewecke Thanks for the reply and welcome back after 7 years. After not looking at it for several hours, it has now appeared. I'm not sure how long it normally takes but it was probably 15-20 minutes after installing that I posted my comment.